# React route: How to display a component in every route except for home? ("/)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

im trying to build a React website with a frontpage and a header that would appear on every part of the app except for homepage ('/). Which would be the easiest way to do it? my code right now looks something like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header /> {/* Header that will show everywhere except for '/' */}
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Frontpage} /> {/* Home frontpage component */}
        <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
        <Route path="/projects" exact component={Projects} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

I was thinking about taking the header component out of app and dragging it into every sub path, although it is not a very effective way of doing it.

Comment: why don't you import the header component in the About and Projects components respectively? It is exactly what components are for.  And take it from the router component.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with composing the Header into the pages that need it? That's not ineffective at all, it's *exactly* what components are made for. Components are intended to be composed, so pop it into the page components.

Comment: The thing is i want to create dynamic links, with a header in all of them. So in order to to that i must load the Header component directly into the app everytime